# Oracle delete from query hanging on a very small dataset

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, sqlplus

Hello I'm trying to run a delete from statement in sqlplus using oracle 11g. It was working fine, because every time I test my program I need to delete a few thousand rows, to test it again and this is just the nature of the program. However, it suddenly stopped deleting the rows and simply hangs now. I'm not sure why.

```
SQL> explain plan for delete from ip_address_usages where datetime= '30-SEP-14 22:44:00';

Explained.

SQL> SELECT * 
FROM   TABLE(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY);  2  

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 250311489

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name              | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | DELETE STATEMENT   |                   |  2295 | 39015 |     7   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  DELETE            | IP_ADDRESS_USAGES |       |       |            |          |
|*  2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| IP_ADDRESS_USAGES |  2295 | 39015 |     7   (0)| 00:00:01 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - filter("DATETIME"=TO_TIMESTAMP('30-SEP-14 22:44:00'))

14 rows selected.

SQL> delete from ip_address_usages where datetime= '30-SEP-14 22:44:00';
```

20 minutes later still sitting there hasn't changed.

Comment: is it being blocked?

Comment: how do i tell that? to me it just sits there and if I ctrl-c it still hangs @Twelfth

Comment: sorry, i'm not the most proficient with oracle 11g...google search came up with this http://www.ora00600.com/wordpress/scripts/11g/find-blocking-sessions-in-oracle-database/

Comment: http://www.orafaq.com/node/854

Comment: Sounds like it's just a very small data set that you created in a different session and didn't commit.